How do I associate IAP Receipts if my App/Game has an authentication mechanic like Firebase auth?
We are currently trying to publish a game that uses Firebase auth to create and sign-in accounts and we also plan to add IAP(both non-consumables and subscription). The problem is, the IAP are tied in with the Google Account which made the transaction meaning that no matter which firebase user is signed in through the account, they could still access the IAP product as long as the said Google account is signed in the device.
We could probably save the receipt on Firebase's real time database and associate it with the current firebase user but I cant perform stuff like checking the subscription status if they used another device with a different Google Account.
Are there any techniques we could do to associate the IAP with the firebase users effectively or should we just conform to Google play login instead? (Where the app logs in the current Google Play account).
-Tried saving the receipt details for future validation but it requires the full payload which might  be difficult to save.
-Added custom claims to Firebase UID (Cant find a way to check subscription status if the firebase user is logged in through a device without the Google Account used for payment).
